# SQL querying all date ranges from one table not between any date ranges of another for given foreign key

Tags: sql

While I've checked other posts about overlapping date ranges I havent found one for this problem.

I have two tables, one for a member's Attribute_spans history

```
MEMBERCODE |   START_DATE   |   END_DATE    | ATTRIBUTE

423223     |   10/01/2020   |  12/31/9999   | Dual
423223     |   11/01/2020   |  11/30/2020   | Cost Share
```

Then there is another table for each members Membership or "Enrollment Span" history.

```
MEMBERCODE |   EFFECTIVE_DATE |  TERM_DATE  |  PLAN_PRODUCT

423223     |   11/01/2020     |  12/31/9999 |  Foo
423223     |   09/01/2020     |  09/30/2020 |  Bar
```

A members most current Attribute span should always be within a a member's most recent Enrollment span, but there can be more than one attribute per enrollment span.

The problem is I want to find all attribute spans from a member's history that do not fully lie within **ANY** Enrollment Span from their history.
For example for this Attribute Span:
10/1/2020   12/31/9999  ** there is no 10/1 period within the any enrollment spans for that member.  It falls within a gap period.

```
SELECT a.MEMBER_NBR, a.START_DATE, A.END_DATE,B.EFFECTIVE_DATE ,B.TERM_DATE,
A.ATTRIBUTE,B.PLAN_PRODUCT
FROM Attribute_Spans A
JOIN Enrollment_Spans B ON A.MemberCode = B.MemberCode
WHERE ((A.Start_Date NOT BETWEEN B.Effective_Date and B.End_Date) AND (A.End_date NOT BETWEEN 
B.Effective_Date and B.End_Date))
AND A.MemberCode = B.MemberCode
```

This doesn't work because it does find Attribute date ranges that do not fall within an Enrollment Span range but that Attribute range does fall within another Enrollment Span range for that particular Member

What I Get

```
MEMBER_CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE   | EFFECTIVE_DATE | TERM_DATE  | ATTRIBUTE | PLAN_PRODUCT
423223      | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 09/01/2020     | 09/30/2020 | Dual      | Bar
423223      | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 11/01/2020     | 12/31/2020 | Dual      | Foo
423223      | 11/01/2020 | 11/30/2020 | 09/01/2020     | 09/30/2020 | Cost Share| Bar
```

What I Expect

```
MEMBER_CODE | START_DATE | END_DATE   | EFFECTIVE_DATE | TERM_DATE  | ATTRIBUTE | PLAN_PRODUCT
423223      | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 09/01/2020     | 09/30/2020 | Dual      | Bar
423223      | 10/01/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 11/01/2020     | 12/31/2020 | Dual      | Foo
```

Some starter code to make the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Attribute_Spans (
MemberCode int,
StartDate date,
EndDate date,
Attribute char(50)
)
INSERT INTO Attribute_Spans (MemberCode,StartDate,EndDate,Attribute)
VALUES (423223,'10/01/2020','12/31/9999','Dual'),
        (423223,'11/01/2020','11/30/2020','Cost Share')

CREATE TABLE Enrollment_Spans (
    MemberCode int,
    Effective_Date date,
    End_Date date,
    PlanProduct char(50)
    )
INSERT INTO Enrollment_Spans (MemberCode,Effective_Date,End_Date,Plan_Product)
VALUES (423223,'09/01/2020','09/30/2020','Foo'),
        (423223,'11/01/2020','12/30/2020','Bar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select a.*
from attribute_spans a
where not exists (select 1
                  from Enrollment_Spans es
                  where es.membercode = a.membercode and
                        a.end_date > es.effective_date and
                        a.start_date < es.end_date 
                 );
```

Two time periods overlap if one starts before the other ends.  And the one ends after the other starts.

This does not consider ending/starting on the same date as being an overlap.  If you want that to count, then change the `>` and `<` to `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do a join to this subquery so I can see the Enrollment Span dates?

Comment: @BenSmith . . . That is a little awkward, because this query return rows when there is *no* overlap.  Perhaps you should ask another question with more clarify on what rows you want to show from the two tables.

Comment: Just the Effective_date and End_date columns and join on MemberCode.  I guess it would produce duplicate values for the Attributes since it would be joining to all the Spans rows.  I figured I'd just make a temp table of the results and then join

Comment: @BenSmith . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.